# Classification: Target with more than 2 classes

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification

I am doing a classification exercise and facing a target with more than 2 categorical classes. I have encoded those classes using the Labelencoder.
The only problem is, I believe I might have to use Onehotencoding after as I do not have only zero and 1 anymore but 0,1,2,3.
The reality is, I just do not know if the Knn or the Decision T. would accept those number as classes. If No, can someone tell me what to do?

### Here my first target:

```
Good 
bad
medium
excellent
```

## I changed it to the following:

```
1
3
2
0
```

I guess my real question is can this be directly used as classes for my target or I need further engineering?

Comment: which model you want to use.?

Comment: Both decision tree classifiers and knn can work with multiclass problems, so you can directly feed them the current labels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the models in Sklearn supports multiclass without onehot encoding. KNN and DecisionTree also support it.

Let's use a toy example to verify this,

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

f = [[1, 2], [3.2, 4.5], [2.0, 0.75], [0.25, 3.68]]

t = [1,
3,
2,
0]

lr = LogisticRegression().fit(f, t)
d = DecisionTreeClassifier().fit(f, t)
r = RandomForestClassifier().fit(f, t)
n = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3).fit(f, t)

lr.predict(f) # array([3, 3, 2, 0])
d.predict(f) # array([3, 3, 2, 0])
r.predict(f) # array([3, 3, 2, 0])
n.predict(f) # array([0, 0, 0, 0])
```

As you can see, all of them support multiclass without any one hot encoding.

If you want to use a Nerual Net, then you may want to one hot encode the labels based on the loss function you use.

Comment: thanks. I thought  I need to onehotencode. so OnehotEncoding is only for  the training set except when I am doing Neural Net if I understand properly?

Comment: Depends on the implementation actually. If you are using sklearn and use knn or tree there is no need for one hot